# Do not count embedded images

Tags: vba, image, outlook

I have the below code which counts the number of attachments in an email, but the problem is it also counts embedded images. Is there a way to exclude embedded images, so they do not get counted?

```
Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectedEmails()
    Dim olSel As Selection
    Dim oMail As Object
    Dim AttCount As Long
    Dim strMsg As String
 
    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    For Each oMail In olSel
        'To confirm if the selected items are all emails
        If oMail.Class <> olMail Then
           strMsg = "Please select mail items only!"
           nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
           Exit Sub
        End If
        'Get the total number of the attachments in selected emails
        AttCount = oMail.Attachments.Count + AttCount
    Next
 
    strMsg = "There are " & AttCount & " attachments in the " & olSel.Count & " selected emails."
    nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Attachments")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next adapted code, please:

```
Sub CountAttachmentsinSelectedEmails()
    Dim olSel As Selection, nRes As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim oMail As Object, AttCount As Long, strMsg As String
        
    Set olSel = Outlook.Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    For Each oMail In olSel
        'To confirm if the selected items are all emails
        If oMail.Class <> olMail Then
           strMsg = "Please select mail items only!"
           nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbExclamation)
           Exit Sub
        End If
        'Get the total number of NOT embeded attachments in selected emails
        Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
        For Each objAtt In oMail.Attachments
            If Not IsEmbedded(objAtt) Then
                AttCount = AttCount + 1
                Debug.Print "Not embedded attachment name: " & objAtt.DisplayName & vbCrLf & _
                      "   from email " & oMail.Subject & vbCrLf & _
                      "   received on: " & oMail.ReceivedTime
            End If
        Next
    Next
 
    strMsg = "There are " & AttCount & " attachments in the " & olSel.count & " selected emails."
    nRes = MsgBox(strMsg, vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count Attachments")
End Sub

Function IsEmbedded(Att As Attachment) As Boolean
    Dim PropAccessor As PropertyAccessor
    Set PropAccessor = Att.PropertyAccessor
    IsEmbedded = (PropAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F") <> "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks looks to be working on initial testing! I will do some more testing and let you know the result.

Comment: @deep_man Still checking...? To help you easily checking, I will adapt the above code to make it retrieving the not embedded attachment name, the mail subject and the receiving time. Please, check such a log in Immediate Window and send some feedback.

Comment: `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` is not, in general, an indicator that an image is used by the HTML body (in the `<img src="cid:xyz">` attribute). Lotus Notes, for example, sets the content-id MIME header on each attachment, even if it is not an image.

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko Did you try the above code on some mails selection? I tried it before posting and skips all embedded attachments. Didn't it do the same in your case?

Comment: yes, because you did not try it on emails where `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` is set on attachments which are not images. Once again, it will probably work in 99% of the cases, but it will break if content-id MIME header is set, which is not at all image related. I have seen emails like that when I fixed a related problem in Redemption.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to actually look at the HTML body and check if any image referes to the attachment, either through the cid attribute (`<img src="cid:xyz">`) or through the file name or url. You'd also need to look at the `PR_ATTACH_HIDDEN` MAPI property.

If using [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) is an option, it exposes `RDOAttachment.Hidden` property:

```
Set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
for each msg in Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
  set rMsg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(msg)
  Debug.Print "-------- " & msg.Subject
  for each attach in rMsg.Attachments
    Debug.Print attach.Hidden & " - " & attach.FileName
  next
next
```